# AngularJS ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I have a very simple AngularJS application where I am trying to display a list of records.

My main index.html code is:

```
<div id="employeeApp" ng-app='employeeApp' ng-controller='EmployeeController'>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>
```

The list.html partial view looks like:

```
div id="listView">
<ul>
    <li name="DataContainer" ng-repeat='employee in employees'>
        <table>
            <tr><td>
                <img ng-src='{{employee.image}}'></img>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td align="center">
                <span name="Name" class="outputData">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="getEmployeeDetail(employee.id)"><div>{{employee.name}}</div><div>{{employee.title}}</div></a>
                </span>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the controller.js code looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('employeeApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.service('EmployeeService', ['$http', function ($http){

this.getEmployees = function () 
{
    return $http.get(baseURL);
};

this.getEmployee = function (id) 
{
    return $http.get(baseURL + '/' + id);
};}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){    $routeProvider
  .when('/employees', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
  })
.when('/employees/:employeeId', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html'
})
.otherwise({ // default
      redirectTo: '/employees'
});}]);

app.controller('EmployeeController', ['$scope', 'EmployeeService', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
 $scope.employees = EmployeeService.getEmployees();
 console.log($scope.employees);

 $scope.getEmployeeDetail = function (id) 
 {
    $scope.employeeDetail =  EmployeeService.getEmployee(id);
    console.log($scope.employeeDetail);
 }}]);
```

My REST service returns me the data that I can see in the browser console but my list is not rendering in the page.

the routing seems to be working fine since I can see list.html getting loaded. However for some reason the the list is showing 2 empty records.

I am wondering i have some basic error either in my html or controller that is breaking the code.

Comment: try setting the controller in the route config .when('/employees', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/list.html', controller: 'EmployeeController'
  })

Comment: what does the output of console.log($scope.employees); look like?

Comment: That doesn't help other than that it results in calling my controller twice instead of once.                                                                                                      The json output looks like: [{"location":"x","email":"someEmail","image":"1.jpg","name":"John","title":"Director","phone":"1234","id":"0"},........]

Answer (score 1):

you controller calling service bit seems strange to me, since `EmployeeService` returns `$http.get(baseURL)`, I would change the controller code to this:

```
app.controller('EmployeeController', ['$scope', 'EmployeeService', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
 EmployeeService.getEmployees().success(function(data){
 $scope.employees = data;
 console.log($scope.employees);
});
```

Comment: Well that doesn't fix the issue and I expected so. console.log($scope.employees) is showing the correct data in the browser log. However for some reason the view is not finding it. My guess either something is wrong with the view or basic error in controller.

Comment: that's very odd, i basically copy exactly your code and I can see the list is binding fine with $scope.employees. I would recommend you start with something simple, just an array of two strings locally ["value1","value2"], check if list.html can bind?